# GTK3 Python Change Single Button Color

Tags: python, button, colors, background-color, gtk3

How to change single button color in Python with GTK3 ? I have two Gtk.Buttons. I want to change second button color to blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with css, try this link for a good example on how to use python gtk and css together.

http://wolfvollprecht.de/blog/gtk-python-and-css-are-an-awesome-combo/

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Generally people do not want that a program overwrite their desktop theme. Anyways, i think that this was possible before Gtk3+ but I'm not really sure, It may be possible using css.

This is the most closer that i can get you.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def button_clicked(button):
    print("Button has been clicked!")

window=Gtk.Window()

button=Gtk.Button(label="Button")
button.connect("clicked", button_clicked)

color = Gdk.color_parse('#234fdb')
button.modify_bg(Gtk.StateType.PRELIGHT, color)

window.add(button)

window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

or

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def button_clicked(button):
    print("Button has been clicked!")

window=Gtk.Window()

button=Gtk.Button(label="Button")
button.connect("clicked", button_clicked)
window.add(button)
window.show_all()

colorh="#0000FF"        
color=Gdk.RGBA()
color.parse(colorh)
color.to_string()

button.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, color)

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I've tried with GTK 3.0, and both examples aren't working. It also said that `modify_bg` and `override_background_color` are deprecated. Maybe that's the reason they didn't work? Any ideas?